# Failed to create new instance of class ru.hpsm.selenide_elements.element_imp.table.ResTable

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Why does this error appear? I don’t understand what is causing this error, I also tried to run the test with a constructor without parameters, but the result is the same - an error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create new instance of class ru.hpsm.selenide_elements.element_imp.table.ResTable
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.page(Selenide.java:634)
    at ru.hpsm.steps.AtomicSteps.Checks.table.CheckTableRes.<clinit>(CheckTableRes.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Here is the method for the step:

```
public class CheckTableRes extends AbstractSteps {

     static ResTable tableResult = page(ResTable.class);

    @Тогда(value = "^(.+) > проверить значения в таблице конфигурационных единиц, в строке под номером ()(\\d+)$", timeout = defaultStepTimeout)
    public void проверитьЗначенияТаблицеРезультатов(String page, String text, Integer i, Map<String, String> args) {
        ResTable.Row row = null;
        if (i == null) {
            text = getStorageData(text);
            row = new ResTable(page, true).getRow(text, true);
        } else {
            row = new ResTable(page, true).getRow(i, true);
        }

        printCheckStepDescription("В строке Таблицы результатов с текстом \"" + row.getElementName() + "\" проверить" +
                "присутствие значений: " + args);
        for (Map.Entry entry : args.entrySet()) {
            String headerColumnName = entry.getKey().toString(), //Получаем ключ = Имя колонки таблицы
                    expectedCellValue = getStorageData(entry.getValue().toString()); // Получаем Значение = Ожидаемое значение колонки в строки

            String cellValue = row.getCell(headerColumnName, true).getText();

            //TODO Переделать условие в if после создания класса DataTime!!!
            if (entry.getValue().toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("время") && Storage.get(entry.getValue().toString()) != null) //Если значение начинается с "Время" и есть в Хранилище,
                // то проверяем время с учетом дельты
                Time.checkDeltaTime(expectedCellValue, cellValue, getTestData().delta);
            else { // иначе сравниваем значения как текст
                Assert.assertEquals("Ошибка. В строке Таблицы Результатов \"" + row.getElementName() + "\" в колонке \"" + headerColumnName + "\" не содержится ожидаемое значение \""
                        + expectedCellValue + "\", а содержится \"" + cellValue + "\"", expectedCellValue.trim(), cellValue.trim());
                System.out.println("в строке в колонке \"" + headerColumnName + " присутствует ожидаемое значение \"" + expectedCellValue + "\"");
            }
        }
        printStepResilt("В строке Таблицы результатов с текстом \"" + row.getElementName() + "\"" +
                "содержатся значения: " + args);
    }
}
```

And the ResTable class itself:
``

```
public class ResTable {
    private final ru.hpsm.page_objects.pages.stand4me.PageAllConfigurationItems resPage = page(ru.hpsm.page_objects.pages.stand4me.PageAllConfigurationItems.class);
    private String context;

    public ResTable(String context, boolean проверитьЧтоТаблицаРезультатовКЕОтображается) {
        this.context = context;
        waitForPageIsUnAvailable();
        if (проверитьЧтоТаблицаРезультатовКЕОтображается) {
            assertTrue("Ошибка. На текущей странице отсутствует Таблица результатов.", isPresent());
        }
    }
```

```
Added a constructor without parameters, but still the same.
```